# Substitution - mistake

Tags: substitution, quantum-mechanics

Where do I mistake please? My computation differ from the result in the text about red terms. Thank you
[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like you made a mistake

Comment: once again x in equation (85)?

Comment: In equation (83) should be $y$.

Comment: Do you appreciate the normalized wavefunctions squared have to integrate to 1 in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the substitution, you do it so that the integral is easier to calculate. $$\int_X|\Psi_0(x)|^2dx=<0|0>=\int_Y|\Psi_0(y)|^2dy$$
That means that you need to account for $\frac{dx}{dy}$ term, or in fact the square root of that.

Comment: thank you and where is a diferential when I compute $\psi$? I thought about dx = x dy but I don't know the reason for that

Comment: When you change variables $\int f(x) dx=\int f(y(x))\frac{dx}{dy(x)}dy$

Comment: How to think of the integral please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: How to think of I should use the formula in your answer? I thought I compute |0>. When I do a substitution, it is always squared?

Comment: No. The reason for that is that both $\Psi_0(x)$ and $|0>$ are normalized functions. The probability is the same (that's a physical constraint). So integrating the wavefunction squared, should give you the same answer.

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand right that $\psi_0(x)=|0>=\int |\psi_0^2(x)|$ when $\psi_0(x)$ is normalized?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87704/discussion-between-andrei-and-elisabeth).